# Es6 React Refs to components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, jsx, refs

How do I get a reference to a component using React with ES6?

I have a Component A

```
class ComponentA extends React.Component {
    doSomethingInComponentA() {
       //do Something here..
    }
}
render(<ComponentA />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

And Another Component B where I want to call ComponentA's method

```
class ComponentB extends React.Component {
    doSomethingInComponentB() {
        ComponentAInstance.doSomethingInComponentA()
    }
}
```

How do I get a reference to ComponentA?
I have tried using

```
var ComponentAInstance = render (<ComponentA />, 
document.getElementById('container'))
export default ComponentAInstance;
```

But Since I am using Webpack and ComponentA.jsx is my entry point I get the error

```
Module not found: Error: a dependency to an entry point is not allowed
```

Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: How are A and B connected?

Comment: They do not have any direct connection.. I just want to know how to call methods from other components

Comment: Have a look at this, if you want to avoid flux: http://andrewhfarmer.com/component-communication/

Answer (score 3):

React encourages you to build applications with primarily one way data flows. If `<ComponentB />` is a direct child of `<ComponentA />` then you can pass data (and functions) to it using props.

```
function ComponentA() {
  const doSomething = () => console.log('I did something');

  return (
    <ComponentB onClick={doSomething} />
  );
}

function ComponentB(props) {
  return (
    <button onClick={props.onClick}>Example<button>
  );
}
```

However, if `<ComponentB />` is a parent of `<ComponentA />`, or has no direct connection to it, then you need to introduce a event/state management system to allow the components to communicate.

The most popular pattern for solving this problem is called [Flux](https://facebook.github.io/flux) and the most popular Flux implementation is [Redux](https://redux.js.org).

With a library like Redux, your components dispatch actions which modify the state of a central store. Other components in your application can listen for changes in the store and respond accordingly.

In your case, you'd need the `doSomethingInComponentB` method to dispatch an action that would change the store. `<ComponentA />` would need to subscribe to changes and call its `doSomethingInComponentA` method after the appropriate state was changed.